# Multiple footnotes break revtex4-1

Tags: footnotes, revtex

I am observing the same behavior that occurred in [a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111746/extra-appearing-in-bibliography-for-footnote-using-revtex4-1). However, I have been able to figure out what is the problem: basically, using multiple footnotes causes the () to appear.

For instance, the following TeX code compiles correctly:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,amsmath,amssymb,jcp,aip,preprint]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

Here's text with one footnote.\footnote{First footnote.}

\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}

\end{document}
```

But the following code returns the extra parentheses:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,amsmath,amssymb,jcp,aip,preprint]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

Here's text with one footnote.\footnote{First footnote.}
But it breaks with two footnotes.\footnote{Second breaks it.}

\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}

\end{document}
```

I can't think of a logical reason why this would be the case, which leads me to believe this is a bug of some sort.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. Your second example works perfectly on my TeX installation (rather old TeXLive 2009 Debian).

Comment: Perhaps this is an OS-specific issue, then? I'm running it under TeXLive 2012 under OS X. And I just rechecked—the code I've posted does fail on my installation, whether I use pdflatex or standard latex.

Comment: This is 'works for me' with an up-to-date TeX Live (2013). Please add `\listfiles` to your input, edit in the resulting `File list` from your `.log` and flag, and I'll reopen.